# Round numbers and keep enough significant digits to differentiate them from their neighbours

Tags: r, rounding

I have a vector of increasing numbers such as the following one:

```
set.seed(1)
numbers  <- cumsum(abs(rnorm(10,100,100)))
# [1]   37.35462  155.71895  172.15609  431.68417  564.63495  582.58811  731.33101  905.16348 1062.74162 1132.20278
```

I want to choose a minimal number of significant digits and then round these numbers, ensuring that I always keep enough digits so consecutive numbers won't be rounded to the same value.

See the following examples (expected output) :

```
magic(numbers, n = 1)
# [1]   40  160  170  400  560  580  700  900 1060 1130
```

- `37.35462` is rounded to `40` because I asked for only one digit here when possible (`n = 1`)
- I can't round `155.71895` to `200` because `172.15609` would be rounded to `200` too by the same rule, so I round `155.71895` to `160`, and `172.15609` to `170`
- I can safely round `431.68417` to `400` as it's far enough from `172.15609` and `564.63495`

etc...

For n = 2 or 3 we would get :

```
magic(numbers, n = 2)
# [1]   37  160  170  430  560  580  730  910 1060 1130

magic(numbers, n = 3)
# [1]   37.4  156  172  432  565  583  731  905 1060 1130
```

My goal is to get readable values of quantiles of a non linear distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#' Minimum preferred significant digits
#'
#' @details
#' Facilitate reducing numbers to their least *distinguishable*
#' significant digits, where "distinguishable" means
#' "between neighbors". This means that if reducing more digits would
#' cause two neighbors to reduce to the same number, then the
#' reduction cannot take place.
#'
#' References:
#'
#' - [Original question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51616332/3358272) (and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617325/3358272))
#' 
#' @param numbers numeric, length 2 or more
#' @param n integer, number of preferred remaining significant digits
#' @return numeric vector
#' @export
#' @md
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' set.seed(1)
#' numbers  <- cumsum(abs(rnorm(10,100,100)))
#' # [1]   37.35462  155.71895  172.15609  431.68417  564.63495  582.58811  731.33101  905.16348 1062.74162 1132.20278
#' magic(numbers, 1)
#' #  [1]   40  160  170  400  560  580  700  900 1060 1130
#' magic(numbers, 2)
#' #  [1]   37  160  170  430  560  580  730  910 1060 1130
#' magic(numbers, 3)
#' #  [1]   37.4  156.0  172.0  432.0  565.0  583.0  731.0  905.0 1060.0 1130.0
#' magic(c(1,2.4,2.6,4),1)
#' # [1] 1 2 3 4
#' }
magic <- function(numbers, n=1L) {
  stopifnot(length(numbers) > 1L)
  logscale <- ceiling(log10(abs(numbers)))
  logdiff <- log10(diff(numbers))
  keepoom <- floor(pmin(c(Inf, logdiff), c(logdiff, Inf)))
  roundpoints <- 5*(10^keepoom)
  out <- signif(numbers, pmax(n, logscale - (1+keepoom)))
  dupes <- duplicated(out)
  if (any(dupes)) {
    dupes <- dupes | c(dupes[-1], FALSE)
    out2 <- signif(numbers, pmax(n, logscale - keepoom))
    out[dupes] <- out2[dupes]
  }
  out
}
```

Sample usage:

```
magic(numbers, 1)
#  [1]   40  160  170  400  560  580  700  900 1060 1130
## [1]   40  160  170  400  560  580  700  900 1060 1130 # yours
magic(numbers, 2)
#  [1]   37  160  170  430  560  580  730  910 1060 1130
## [1]   37  160  170  430  560  580  730  910 1060 1130 # yours
magic(numbers, 3)
#  [1]   37.4  156.0  172.0  432.0  565.0  583.0  731.0  905.0 1060.0 1130.0
## [1]   37.4  156  172  432  565  583  731  905 1060 1130 # yours
magic(c(1,2.4,2.6,4),1)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
## [1] 1:4 # yours, from comments
```

Comment: beautiful, I think that nails it, I'll leave the tick mark hanging a little as I'm curious to see different approaches and come back soon but that'll be hard to beat.

Comment: A fully vectorized solution ! Great answer !

Comment: If this goes into a paper or a package, please cite my vectorizing-awesomeness ;-)

Comment: Updated code to deal with negatives (I know you intend it for quantiles, but it doesn't hurt) and to formalize it a little.

Comment: I found another difference between my solution and yours, try `magic(c(1,2.4,2.6,4),1)` (your method doesn't change it, mine returns `1:4`. You round the numbers differently according to their diff, not according to them rounding to the same value. This actually makes more sense to me and I'll use this, but it's slightly at odds with current function description.

Comment: Good corner-case, and good catch. I have a fix that does `signif` twice, once with `keepoom+1` and check for dupes; if none, keep it (your output), but expecting at least one dupe and running with `keepoom` unchanged. Thoughts?

Comment: Yours will still be faster in several cases, esp since this is doing `signif` potentially/usually twice, but I'm not certain there's a better easy way to determine if two neighbors are on different sides of a rounding point.

Comment: This solution appears to be converging on your recursive solution :-)

Comment: As I am re-reading your comment ... are you saying `1:4` makes more sense, or my original `c(1,2.4,2.6,4)`?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I actually meant that your initial solution made more sense to me for my use cases, even though isn't a 100% accurate answer to my question (I'm saying my question was wrong and your answer was right basically). If I'm working with intervals, which is likely with this function, the actual width of the middle interval from my example is `0.2` originally, and if I round everything it becomes `1`. This could be problematic and your original solution makes such distortions impossible.

Comment: The disadvantage of your initial solution is that it's a bit harder to explain/understand. I believe the best way to solve the ambiguity is to be explicit about it and add a boolean parameter so we can choose between both.

Comment: @r2evans This day finally came ;). https://github.com/moodymudskipper/cutr/blob/master/R/smart_signif.R . Let me know if you want to be credited differently .

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a recursive option, borrowing `signif` from @r2evans :

```
magic <- function(numbers,n){
  rounded <- signif(numbers,n)
  dupes   <- duplicated(rounded) | duplicated(rounded,fromLast = TRUE) 
  if (any(dupes)) rounded[dupes] <- magic(numbers[dupes], n+1)
  rounded
}

magic(numbers,1)
# [1]   40  160  170  400  560  580  700  900 1060 1130
magic(numbers,2)
# [1]   37  160  170  430  560  580  730  910 1060 1130
magic(numbers,3)
# [1]   37.4  156.0  172.0  432.0  565.0  583.0  731.0  905.0 1060.0 1130.0
```

As mentioned by @DigEmAll in the comments it fails when duplicates are present in the original vector (which could indeed happen with my stated use case).

Comment: I definitely prefer yours ;) (And I read there was no good recursive, but I don't know much)

Comment: I'm not competing, elegant-recursive can be good and at times more readable (and a nice challenge), where "elegant" to me means *"don't do what I often did as an undergrad and create a resource denial-of-service on the server ..."*.

Comment: I learned lisp and scheme well before R, so tail-recursion (when done right) seems natural to me. Unfortunately, since R doesn't do tail-recursion perfectly well, it is often frowned-upon.

Comment: strangely, my solution was +- twice faster on a microbenchmark of `magic(numbers,3)`, which surprises me. that being said performance will never be a concern with that function anyway. Maybe it'd be different on a longer vector. (tested with your original solution)

Comment: I'm not too surprised, mine always uses 2 `log10` and a `diff` in addition to `signif`, yours is a bit more reactive. This solution is fairly elegant, too, though I wonder if it's possible to find a sequence that causes either solutions to never find an acceptable reduction. (I believe that the two solutions are effectively equivalent with no differently-handled corner cases. \*shrug\*)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: your solution is probably faster on smaller vectors and when there aren't many recursions steps due to duplicates

Comment: BTW, your solution fails (infinite recursion, so stackoverflow error, yeah!) in case of duplicate numbers in the original vector...the r2evans version does not. You should add a maximum recursion check

Comment: I stand corrected, corner-case found. Good catch, @digEmAll!

Comment: You can get around that by checking for dupes *first* and operating on the unique values, but now you get into more subsetting and such.

Comment: Yes I won't bother,  it won't be the chosen solution so better keep it easy to understand for readers.

Answer (score -1):

```
i=0
while(length(unique(numbers))==length(numbers)&&i<20){i<-i+1;numbers<-round(numbers,digits=(20-i));}
```

This code runs for as long as either numbers are no longer of equal length or your i is exceeded, when you have just very small disparities, just adjust the 20 to an even higher value.

Hope that helps.

> I want to choose a minimal number of significant digits and then round
>   these numbers, ensuring that I always keep enough digits so
>   consecutive numbers won't be rounded to the same value.

Was the statement, my result is:

```
     set.seed(1)
    numbers  <- cumsum(abs(rnorm(10,100,100)))
numbers<-numbers/10000
     i=0
     while(length(unique(numbers))==length(numbers)&&i<20){i<-i+1;numbers<-round(numbers,digits=(20-i));}
```

Edit: I see where the problem is now: You want to round not only the digits but values above the comma, if you want to do that, just transform your variables, divide them by (in this case 10000) and multiply them after. But I guess I found another mistake, this code actually just provides the i, so you need to run:

`set.seed(1) 
numbers  <- cumsum(abs(rnorm(10,100,100)))`

and then use the i from before, to run

```
round(numbers/10000,digits=(20-i+1))*10000
```

Sorry for that mess had to leave and just a short look at the result.

Comment: it doesn't give the expected output, and there's no `n` parameter

Comment: But that parameter is digits

Comment: see answer from @r2evans to see what I expected